# If installing a nuget in a class library do I also have to add it to the client app?

Tags: windows, xamarin, nuget, class-library, .net-standard-2.0

I have a class library such as .NET Standard 2.0 that uses a nuget. I have multiple clients that use this class library. Will the client automatically get the required files from the class library references or do I need to install the same nugets used in class libraries in client apps that consume the library?

Comment: It depends on how you ship your class library to such clients. Usually people publish a NuGet package, and specify other NuGet packages as references.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the nuget, generally in nuget's which are purely .net based won't be needed to be installed on the platform projects, for example, `Json.net`.
But let's say that you are using a nuget which interacts with the native api, under the hood, like Rg.Plugins.Popup, which lets you create UI basically which is not entirely only .NET thing, so it will be required to be installed on all the platforms.

There's really not a way that you can differentiate between them, but if you check the nuget's Github page, they would generally mention whether you need to install it on platform projects or not.

But you can assume that something which affects the UI would be needed to be installed on the platform project, whereas something which does nothing but pure logical processing would only be required to be installed to your .NET standard library.